# Discord.js Read a link just clicked

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

I have a link in a message like this:

> To do what you want you need to click [this link](http://google.com).

I want to recover the anchor of the link, in this case, http://google.com, when the user clicks it.

I actually solved the problem using my webserver but it opens the browser for few seconds and I don't like it very much.

I tried to find something in the events like client.on("link-tapped") but I hadn't very much luck.

The purpose is to be able to insert a bot command in a text, make it look like a link, and let the user click it to execute the command (like telegram does).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is not possible. Discord provides no API for this. You might be able to achieve this by creating a custom plugin for BetterDiscord, but it's against Discord's Terms of Service.

Comment: @Jakye tnx for your answer. Maybe something to play around without bothrering Discord Terms of Service? I actually use something like webhooks Bqaasically i have a rest api that serve the purpose, it receive the content and write it back using something similar to webhooks (i use a temp table in my database to achieve this but i need to co outside discord for a moment...)

Comment: i just need to eliminate the passage from the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with the Discord API.

Other Bot Creators use Reactions for this. The Bot creates a message and reacts with certain emotes to the message. If the user presses one of these emotes, a specific action will be executed.